# How to set max height constraint for a view?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a view and I want it's height to be equal to %20 of its parent. However, its height should be less than 64px. How to set this up in storyboard?

Comment: You can add 2 Height constraints... make one 20% of the parent, and the other `<= 64`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this (the two views are called Superview and Subview; ignore everything but the first and last constraints in the screenshot):

[image]

The subview has an internal height constraint that's a less-than-or-equal-to-64 constraint. The height equality constraint between the superview and subview has a multiplier of `0.2` (that's your 20%) but a priority of 999.

Result (superview is black, subview is white, subview is at top of superview): when the superview is short, subview is 20% of its height:

[image]

... but when superview is tall, subview cannot grow beyond 64 points in height. (Points, not px. Points are not pixels. Be careful.)

[image]